# Problem to find the Thévenin resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis

I need to find the Thévenin resistance and FEM of this circuit:

[image]

I am a little confused why my answer is wrong. I mean, we could just calculate the resistance equivalent and go on with the calculations, but i really want t know where is the error in my attempt here:

First, i calculated the current through the circuit. Of course nothing flows on the resistance 7 Ohms, so the circuit is just the above part. Using basic equation: \$80-6I-20-6I => 60 = 12I => I = 5 A\$, so that the EFM would be \$\epsilon = -20-6*5 = -50 V\$.

Now we need to calculate the current of the short circuit, where the resistor next to 20V is zero. \$80-20-6I_{sc}=0 => I_{sc}= 10 A\$. So technically, the equivalent resistance would be \$\epsilon=RI_{sc} => R = 5 Ohms\$. But this is wrong... Why?

Comment: Draw a wire for your short circuit and show where \$I_{SC}\$ is with arrow.  Then you should see that you have two loops.

Comment: LSS, another way "to see" is to think about what would happen if you forced (jammed it in, somehow) one amp into those leads. Where would that current go? Through what resistances? Would any of those resistors form up into parallel paths for the current? Do the voltage sources affect this thought experiment in any way? (Keep in mind that your mystery current-jammer will overwhelm anything in its way, no matter what.) You can see, for example, that all of the current *must* go through the \$7\:\Omega\$ resistor, right? Can't help it. So you know it's that much, if not more resistance, right?

Comment: Intuitively you should see the output impedance is 10 ohms, so what is the voltage?

Comment: You say "the resistor next to 20V is zero"  What does that mean? The short circuit current is calculated with the external terminals shorted. You have correct voltage. You can simply look at it and see that the impedance is 10 ohms (consider the two voltage sources as shorts), but you can also calculate the short circuit current and derive the resistance, with a lot more effort.

Answer (score 1):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqxmh4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_3=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

We also know that \$\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2:=\text{V}_\text{n}\$.

Now, we can set up a Mathematica-code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I3 == I1 + I2, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == (0 - V2)/R2, 
   I3 == (V1 - V3)/R3, I3 == V3/R4, V1 - V2 == Vn}, {I1, I2, I3, V1, 
   V2, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (R2 Vi + (R3 + R4) (Vi - Vn))/(
   R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  I2 -> (-(R3 + R4) Vi + (R1 + R3 + R4) Vn)/(
   R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  I3 -> (R2 Vi + R1 Vn)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V1 -> ((R3 + R4) (R2 Vi + R1 Vn))/(
   R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V2 -> (R2 (R3 + R4) Vi - R2 (R1 + R3 + R4) Vn)/(
   R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V3 -> (R4 (R2 Vi + R1 Vn))/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4))}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_3\$ and letting \$\text{R}_4\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{R}_1\text{V}_\text{n}+\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag3$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_3\$ and letting \$\text{R}_4\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}+\text{R}_1\text{V}_\text{n}}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}\tag4$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\text{R}_3+\frac{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R4 (R2 Vi + R1 Vn))/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  R4 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=(R2 Vi + R1 Vn)/(R1 + R2)

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R2 Vi + R1 Vn)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), R4 -> 0]]

Out[3]=(R2 Vi + R1 Vn)/(R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3))

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=(R1 R2)/(R1 + R2) + R3
```

So, using your values we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{th}=50\space\text{V}\tag6$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{th}=5\space\text{A}\tag7$$
- $$\text{R}_\text{th}=10\space\Omega\tag8$$

Comment: Please double-check your answer, Because Rth and Vth (Ith) doesn't look right.

Comment: @G36 I am sorry, I made a silly mistake. I edited my answer, now it is right.

Comment: @Carl Sure, but this method does work always. Of course there is a faster way, but in order to learn it, I think this is a good method to start.